# So I'm trying to sort the list in ascending order without using the sort function in C# and I'm a bit new so I was wondering how could I do it?

Tags: c#, arraylist, while-loop, foreach

```
namespace Activity4 
{
  class Worksheet4
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //I'm limiting the user input to just 5
  
      List<int> Nums = new List<int>();
      while (Nums.Count < 5)
      {

            Console.Write("Enter the 1st number:");
            int Nums1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Nums.Add(Nums1);
            Console.Write("Enter the 2nd number:");
            int Nums2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Nums.Add(Nums2);
            Console.Write("Enter the 3rd number:");
            int Nums3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Nums.Add(Nums3);
            Console.Write("Enter the 4th number:");
            int Nums4 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Nums.Add(Nums4);
            Console.Write("Enter the 5th number:");
            int Nums5 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Nums.Add(Nums5);
```

> here's the part where I don't really know how I am supposed to sort it in ascending order without using the sort function and if there is a simpler way for me to individually identify each input which one is lower or not please do enlighten me

```
            foreach (int x in Nums)
            {
              Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
         }   
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: *"how I am supposed to sort it"* - **Normally** one would use built-in functionality to accomplish this task.  *"without using the sort function"* - If you don't want to use built-in functionality then you would write your own.  Look up "sorting algorithms", pick one, and make an attempt.  When you try, what specifically doesn't work as expected?

Comment: What have you tried? It helps to write code to do what you would if you had numbers in front of you. How would you sort these numbers with your brain on a piece of paper? Look at the first one, and if its less than the second move it over, then look at the third etc..

Comment: If this a task given to you (or self-assigned) to help understanding and practicing sorting algorithms, i would suggest to start with the humble (albeit very slow) [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) which should be relatively easy to understand because it is rather simple...

Comment: I would note that since sorting algorithms is a standard assignment when introducing algorithms, there are **tons** of resources on the topic if you search around a bit. All different kinds of algorithms, implementations in just about every language, intuitive visualizations, benchmarks, just about whatever you want. So I would suggest doing a little bit more research before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LINQ`'s [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-6.0):

```
var sortedAscending = Nums.OrderBy(n => n);
foreach(int num in sortedAscending)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

If you want the opposite direction use `OrderByDescending`.

Both methods don't create a new collection and don't modify the source-collection. They are using deferred execution, which means that they are just the instruction to perform the sort, not the actual sorting. If you want to create a new collection you can append  `ToList` or `ToArray`.

They are using a stable sort(unlike [`List.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-6.0)), so the order of equal numbers will stay same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple logic if you don't want to use any `Sort` or `OrderBy` function.

```
List<int> UnSortedNums = new List<int>();
UnSortedNums.Add(20);
UnSortedNums.Add(50);
UnSortedNums.Add(10);
UnSortedNums.Add(10);
UnSortedNums.Add(30);

List<int> AscendingNums = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < UnSortedNums.Count; i++)
{
    if(UnSortedNums.Any(x => !AscendingNums.Contains(x)))
    {
        int Min = UnSortedNums.Where(x => !AscendingNums.Contains(x)).Min();
        int Count = UnSortedNums.Where(x => x == Min).Count();
        for (int j = 0; j < Count; j++)
        {
            AscendingNums.Add(Min);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work correctly if a number occurs multiple times. And it looks like complexity O(N^3) which is worse than almost all common algorithms (except slowsort)